# Get the first and last item in an Array - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the first and last item in array and display them in an object.

What i did is that I use the first and last function and then assign the first item as the key and the last item as the value.

```
var myArray = ['Rodel', 'Mike', 'Ronnie', 'Betus'];

function firstAndLast(array) {

var firstItem = myArray.first;
var lastItem = myArray.last;

 var objOutput = {
   firstItem : lastItem 
  };

}

var display = transformFirstAndLast(myArray);

console.log(display);
```

however this one gets me into trouble. It says undefined. Any idea why is that?

Comment: What does `myArray.first` do? The first item is the item with the index `0`.

Comment: When looking for an array, pretty sure it'd be `myArray[0]` for the first object and `myArray[myArray.length - 1]` for the last.

Comment: {Rodel: "Betus"}

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've modified your code :

```js
var myArray = ['Rodel', 'Mike', 'Ronnie', 'Betus'];

function firstAndLast(array) {

var firstItem = myArray[0];
var lastItem = myArray[myArray.length-1];

 var objOutput = {
   first : firstItem,
   last : lastItem
  };

return objOutput;
}

var display = firstAndLast(myArray);

console.log(display);
```

**UPDATE: New Modification**

```js
var myArray = ['Rodel', 'Mike', 'Ronnie', 'Betus'];

function firstAndLast(array) {

var firstItem = myArray[0];
var lastItem = myArray[myArray.length-1];

var objOutput = {};
objOutput[firstItem]=lastItem

return objOutput;
}

var display = firstAndLast(myArray);

console.log(display);
```

Comment: What if the desired output is `{Rodel: "Betus"}`, as implied by the `{ firstItem : lastItem }` in the OP's code?

Comment: @nnnnnn "I am trying to get the first and last item in array and `display them` in an object."

Comment: the output must be {Rodel: "Betus"}

Comment: var objOutput = {
   firstItem : lastItem
  }; doesnt work

Comment: @GaaraItachiUchiha it totally "does work", just not in the way you expect it to. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/251311

Comment: @Ashraf - If you go just on that sentence then `console.log(myArray)` is the only code needed, because `myArray` is already a type of object.

Comment: Not that it necessarily matters, but if the first item isn't of a simple type (`boolean`, `number`, `string`), then your edited answer would fail.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen I agree , the requirement itself is a bit strange .

Answer (score 16):

With ES6 and destructuring:

```
const myArray = ['Rodel', 'Mike', 'Ronnie', 'Betus'];

const { 0: first, length, [length -1]: last } = myArray //getting first and last el from array
const obj = { first, last }

console.log(obj) // {  first: "Rodel",  last: "Betus" }
```

Answer (score 16):

As of 2021, you can use **Array.prototype.at()**

```
let colors = ['red',  'green', 'blue']

let first = colors.at(0) // red
let last = colors.at(-1) // blue
```

To read more about [Array.prototype.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

Answer (score 13):

ES6

```
var objOutput = { [myArray[0]]: [...myArray].pop() }
```

```js
var myArray = ['Rodel', 'Mike', 'Ronnie', 'Betus'];

var objOutput = { [myArray[0]]: [...myArray].pop() }

console.log(objOutput);
```

Comment: No offense but this looks way worse than the non-ES6 variants :)

Comment: Because the above answers are more helpful/cleaner.

Comment: @Bataleon the value of this answer is that it is short and different than other answers, so it gives more choice to the programmer and increases his knowledge of potential opportunities

Comment: Yes, but the cognitive load of understanding the code is higher than the alternative approaches. Should we not all be aiming to write _readable_ code? :)

Comment: @Bataleon vote down means "wrong", this is not a wrong answer. If you don't like an answer, feel free to comment but if it's really bad it won't get enough vote ups. Vote down is a strong negative, that's why StackOverflow will give you negative points when you vote down, so please use them carefully.

Comment: @orad Thanks, I didn't realise down voting was seen as so "serious". To quote the SO docs: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." I have since removed my downvote (because the answer works). However, it seems the response is more about the author showing off their JavaScript chops, rather than providing a _readable_ solution.

Comment: While this might look pretty and fancy, I would not recommended it as it could potentially trigger two copies!!

Answer (score 1):

Another variation of roli answer

```
function firstAndLast(array) {
    return { [[...array].shift()]: [...array].pop() };
}
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using a simple array filter:

```
const myArray = ['one', 2, 3, 4, 5];
const filterFirstLast = (e, i, a) => i === 0 || i === a.length - 1;
const [ first, last ] = myArray.filter(filterFirstLast);
console.log(first, last); // outputs: 'one', 5

// dealing with insufficient input is another topic (input array length < 2)
console.log(['one'].filter(filterFirstLast )); // outputs: ['one']
console.log([].filter(filterFirstLast )); // outputs: []
```

transforming to something else is as easy

```
const obj = { [first]: last }; // will be: { one: 5 }, but never { one: "one" }
// OR, if you allow ['one'] to apply for both, if last is nullish (e.g. undefined, null, ""):
const obj = { [first]: last || first }; // will be: { one: 5 }, can be { one: "one" }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your `first` and `last` properties work as you want, define them as properties with "getters" on the array prototype.

(You also have an inconsistency between `firstAndLastArray` and `transformFirstAndLast`, which needed to be fixed.)

Returning `{firstName: lastName}` will not do what you presumably want, since it will yield the key `firstName`. To use the actual first name as the key, use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) (`{[firstName]: lastName}`).

```js
Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, {
  first: { get() { return this[0]; }},
  last:  { get() { return this[this.length - 1]; }}
});

var myArray = ['Rodel', 'Mike', 'Ronnie', 'Betus'];

function firstAndLast(array) {
  var firstItem = myArray.first;
  var lastItem = myArray.last;
  
  return {[firstItem]: lastItem};
}

var display = firstAndLast(myArray);

console.log(display);
```

Or, much more simply, just

```
function firstAndLast(array) {
  return {[array[0]]: array[array.length - 1]};
}
```

If you don't want to, or cannot, use computed property names, then

```
function firstAndLast(array) {
  var result = {};
  result[array[0]] = array[array.length - 1];
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Rodel: Bestus

Not "firstItem: Bestus"

Comment: OP said this a million times

Comment: @TyQ. if I asked for a lamborghini million times would you please get it to me?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :-

```
var myArray = ['Rodel', 'Mike', 'Ronnie', 'Betus'];

function firstAndLast(myArr) {

    var firstItem = myArr[0];
    var lastItem = myArr[myArr.length - 1];
    var objOutput = {}; 
    objOutput[firstItem] = lastItem;
    return objOutput;
}

var display = firstAndLast(myArray);

console.log(display);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I have another idea... for ex.:

```
const all = ['food', 'clean', 'cat', 'shower', 'work out']
console.log(`you have ${all.length} all!`)
console.log(`Todo: ${all[0]}`)
console.log(`Todo: ${all[all.length - 1]}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to find out the first and last value of an array

```js
var array = ['Rodel', 'Mike', 'Ronnie', 'Betus'];

let {0 : a ,[array.length - 1] : b} = array;

 var objOutput = {
   first : a,
   last:b
  };

console.log(objOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In Array :- Check first and last element in array are same or not.. 
function hasSame(arr1, arr2) {
    for(i=0; i <arr1.length ; i++) {
    for(j=0; j <arr2.length ; j++) {
        if(arr1[0] === arr2[0] && arr1[2] ===  arr2[2]) {
            return true
        } else
          return false;
    }
}
}

console.log(hasSame(
    ["white bread", "lettuce", "toast"],
    ["white bread", "tomato", "toast"]
))
```

Comment: It will be better if you add explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change last to first

```
const x=[1,2,3]
x.unshift(x.splice(x.length-1,1)[0])
console.log(x) // [ 3, 1, 2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Regular answer

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const first = arr.at(0);
const last = arr.at(-1);
```

##### Code golf one-liner

<sup>Might be somewhat more readable and easy to digest than other one-liner answers.</sup>

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const [first, last] = [0, -1].map(i => arr.at(i));
```